# Getting Maximum call stack error while switching to Frame in Protractor TypeScript Framework

Tags: typescript, protractor

I have written the below generic method for switch to frame and it throws the "Maximum call stack size exceeded error"

My Framework is a combination of Cucumber with TypeScript in Protractor.

Switch to Frame

```
         * @param element
         * @param elementName
         */
         async switchToFrame(element: ElementFinder, elementName: string) 
         {
            await this.waitForPageToLoad();
            await this.waitForElementToBeVisible(element, elementName);
            console.log('Switching to frame');
            await browser.switchTo().frame(element);
            await element.getWebElement();
            await browser.sleep(3000);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you prob need to provide the full code of the current file, waitForPageToLoad, getWebElement and waitForElementToBeVisible methods code also and where they are located.

Until you do this, a shot in the dark - try renaming `element` argument to `$element`. you may be overriding protractor's `element` object and that causes issues